# get http data from function isntead of ngOnit in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am trying to call data from a service using setInterval.
When I am calling it from ngOnInit it is working fine.
But when I am calling it through any other function it is giving me below error:
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

'''

```
public apiCall(mints:number){
   console.log("from setinterval"); 
//  console.log("api called");
//  this.refInrvl=setInterval(()=>{  
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(resp=>{
        this.storeD=resp;
      }); 
  //  },3000)
  }
  public refreshSearch(){
    console.log(this.refMints);
    this.setIntvl();

  }
  public refreshList(refMints:number){
    //this.refMints=refMints;
    console.log("Sel Number",this.refMints);
    this.setIntvl();
  }
  public setIntvl(){
  this.refInrvl=setInterval(this.apiCall,(this.refMints*300*60),this.refMints);
  }
```

'''

Comment: are you http a HttpClient? `constructor(private http:HttpClient){}`, should work. BTW I prefer use `timer` rxjs operator instead a setInterval

Comment: Most probably  'this.' is not pointing to the right object httpClient injected in your constructor.

Comment: Context of `this` is missing when this.apiCall is passed to setInterval. use `this.apiCall.bind(this)`.

Comment: @Eliseo I have added already in constructor http you can see in below code.
public refMints:number=1;
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiCall(this.refMints);
}
I wanted to use both interval and clearinterval hence using setinterval.

Comment: @enno.void, Thanks for your solution, it worked at myside. Thank you so much...!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class yourService {
baseUrl: string;
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  }
public apiCall() Promise<any>{
      this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl).toPromise();
      //.subscribe(resp=>{this.storeD=resp;}); 
  }

}
```

To resolve the promise, in any component inject the service into the constructor, and resolve the promise :

```
async getYorData() {
await this.serviceInComponent.apiCall().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I recommend using setTime or setInterval in the component itself for runtime reasons and some unpredictable behavior of the timed functions.

```
  refreshResponse(time: number){
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await this.serviceInComponent.apiCall().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, time);
  }

console.log(refreshResponse(3000))
```